# DatePicker and FullCalendar is always a day short

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker, fullcalendar

I am using this code to insert bookings in to a database.

### DatePicker

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp1, #dp2').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>
```

### SQL

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (forename, surname, badge, colour, start, end) VALUES (:forename, :surname, :badge, :colour, STR_TO_DATE(:dp1,'%Y-%m-%d'), STR_TO_DATE(:dp2,'%Y-%m-%d'))");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindParam("$key", $_POST[$key]);
}

$stmt->execute();

header("Location: /");
?>
```

**SQL Table**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM bookings;
+----+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | forename | surname | badge | colour | start               | end                 | timestamp           |
+----+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | John     | Doe     | 1     | black  | 2014-10-27 00:00:00 | 2014-10-31 00:00:00 | 2014-10-21 13:11:50 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is a Monday to Friday booking but shows as Monday to Thursday.

[image]

**SQL Query**

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings");

$stmt->execute();

$return_array = array();
$event_array;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $event_array = array();

  $event_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $event_array['title'] = $row['forename'] ." ". $row['surname'];
  $event_array['start'] = $row['start'];
  $event_array['end'] = $row['end'];
  $event_array['allDay'] = true;

  $event_array['className'] = $row['colour'];

  array_push($return_array, $event_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_array);
?>
```

### FullCalendar

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'data.php',
          type: 'POST'
        }
      ]
    })
  });
</script>
```

### Problem

For example if I pick the start date as Monday and end date as Friday the calendar then shows a booking that starts on Monday and ends on Thursday, not Friday.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you post the dates of the datepicker to the server; nor what exactly happens at data.php

Comment: If I remember correctly, end day is always excluded for allday events.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I removed `$event_array['allDay'] = true;` and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the `end` in the events array is exclusive.

See also the docs: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

> The exclusive date/time an event ends. Optional.
>
> A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this
>   will become a real Moment object.
>
> It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example,
>   if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the
>   event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!

Comment: Is it possible to do `STR_TO_DATE(:dp2,'%Y-%m-%d')` but add an extra day at the same time?

Comment: Try simply moving the end date a few hours later, perhaps directly on your database, and see what happens.

Comment: I updated the time to 06:00:00 and it still doesn't include Friday on the calendar.

Comment: For now I am doing `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, Forename, Surname, Start, DATE_ADD(End, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS End, Colour FROM bookings");` but this is real messy.

Comment: That's how it works now... the `end` must be immediately after the actual end of event.